# Remove " " brackets from array Keys in Twig

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, symfony, twig

Twig malforms my array keys and adds " " brackets to my array keys passed from a symfony2 controller.

The array is passed to a Javascript graphics library which requires:

```
[{x:"disabled test object",y:"17",label:"disabled test object"}]
```

Instead `{{ array|json_encode|raw }}` as suggested by the Twig docs and other SO questions I've read through returns the unreadable:

```
[{"x":"disabled test object","y":"17","label":"disabled test object"}]
```

I figure this should not be complicated to achieve but going through the json_encode options so far has not resulted in a clear answer. I am unsure whether there is something I can do from PHP so I've added the tag for now.

EDIT:

I am now attempting to step through the array manually using Twig. `{{dump(points)}}` confirms it is filled properly

```
{% set points = chart.dataPoints|json_encode|raw %} <=== this was the problem
dataPoints:
     {% for point in points %}
         {{ dump(point) }}
         { x: {{ point.x }}, y: {{ point.y }}, label: {{ point.label }} }
         {% if loop.lastIndex != true %}
             ,
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

But this does not work either as the dump is never reached. Is this the correct way of trying to access objects in a `foreach` via Twig though? This code is an amalgamation of several Twig docs tutorials.

EDIT 2, the solution:

The line `{% set points = chart.dataPoints|json_encode|raw %}` turned the whole array into a single string, making it impossible for javascript to interpret as an array. After removing this, all that was left was to make sure the query result had the proper array keys and to transform the X-axis data before passing it to Twig.

```
$i = 0;
$points = array();
/** @var array $query_result*/
foreach($query_result as &$row) {
  foreach($row as $value) {
   $point[] = [
    'x'  => ($i)*10,
    'y' => $value['y'],
    'label' => $value['label']
   ];
   $points[$i] = $point;
   $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the array in JavaScript?

Comment: To be more specific, I am trying to draw graphics with CanvasJS. Example: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-column-chart/

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `json_encode()` in your controller, store the resulting string in a variable and display it with Twig (without `|json_encode|raw`).

Comment: print_r result: Array ( [title] => Array test [dataPoints] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => disabled test object [y] => 17 [label] => disabled test object ) ) ) and Symfony expects an array in this->render from what I can tell

Comment: *returns the unreadable* This code is readable (I tested it with an [online JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)). The library should read these keys even if they have quotes.

Comment: That's what I figured but those " " quotes are the only difference. Manually inserting data without the quotes works fine. Does the CanvasJS work for you? I suspect it might be a Twig + CanvasJS combination problem.

Comment: If I add quotes around `x` and `y` on the first example of this page it works: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-column-chart/ It looks like quotes are not a problem for this library.

Comment: This code `x: {{ point.x }}` won't work since strings are not in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are not a problem for CanvasJS. As you can see in the example below, `"x":` works (I took [this example](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-column-chart/)):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "Top Oil Reserves"
      },
        data: [{
        dataPoints: [
          { x: 1, y: 297571, label: "Venezuela"},
          { "x": 2, "y": 267017,  label: "Saudi" }
        ]
      }]
    });
    
    chart.render();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

So we need to provide a JSON array for `dataPoints:`

1. Define the PHP array in your Controller's function and pass it to the template:

```php
public function myAction()
{
    // …

    $json = array(
        array(
            'x' => 1,
            'y' => 297571,
            'label' => 'Venezuela',
        ),
        array(
            'x' => 2,
            'y' => 267017,
            'label' => 'Saudi',
        ),
    );

    return array(
        // …
        'json' => $json,
    );
}
```

2. Display the array in the template and pass it to `dataPoints` :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var json = {{ json|json_encode|raw }};
    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
            title:{
                text: "Top Oil Reserves"
            },
            data: [{
                dataPoints: json
            }]
        });

        chart.render();
    }
</script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

The rendered output will be:

```javascript
// …
<script>
    var json = [{"x":1,"y":297571,"label":"Venezuela"},{"x":2,"y":267017,"label":"Saudi"}];
// …
```

CanvasJS will be able to read this JavaScript array and display the chart.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first one is a JavaScript object, and the second one is JSON, try running JSON.parse on the string like this to convert it back in to an object:

```
var fixed = JSON.parse('[{"x":"disabled test object","y":"17","label":"disabled test object"}]');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I am trying to parse "[{"x":"disabled test object","y":"17","label":"disabled test object"}]" using the above method which phpstorm finds and autosuggests flawlessly but it only returns null. Do I require extra files for this or some sort of import?

Comment: You shouldn't require anything extra to use that JavaScript function, did you try parsing it and then console.log()-ing it to see what comes out? Or is that how you got null?

Comment: I window.alert()-ed both the array before and after parsing. Before it is filled, after it is null. I am now attempting to manually step through the array via Twig, I will update the question in a minute.

Comment: @G_V *I am trying to parse "[{"x"* The array should not be into quotes.

Comment: @A.L haha apparently the json_encode|raw turned the whole array into a single String which made it unreadable. I've removed that and now it works. Update your answer and I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: @G_V What did you remove? Something in the Twig template?

Comment: @A.L yes, the conversion part from passed PHP array > json > javascript: {% set points = chart.dataPoints|json_encode|raw %}